# Hgweb under iis: 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: No hgweb templates found in []

Tags: windows, iis, mercurial

I am setting up Mercurial under IIS on Windows 7 using [these instructions](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/)
I have got to the point where I test an empty repository, and I am getting the following error

```
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hg\hgweb.cgi in ()
     15 
     16 from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
     17 from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
     18 application = hgweb('c:\inetpub\wwwroot\hg\hgweb.config')
=>   19 wsgicgi.launch(application)
wsgicgi = <module 'mercurial.hgweb.wsgicgi' from 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\hg\mercurial\hgweb\wsgicgi.pyc'>, wsgicgi.launch = <function launch>, application = <mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod.hgwebdir object>
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mercurial\hgweb\wsgicgi.pyc in launch(application=<mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod.hgwebdir object>)
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc in __call__(self=<mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod.hgwebdir object>, env={'ALLUSERSPROFILE': r'C:\ProgramData', 'APPDATA': r'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming', 'APP_POOL_ID': 'DefaultAppPool', 'AUTH_PASSWORD': '', 'AUTH_TYPE': '', 'AUTH_USER': '', 'CERT_COOKIE': '', 'CERT_FLAGS': '', 'CERT_ISSUER': '', 'CERT_SERIALNUMBER': '', ...}, respond=<function start_response>)
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc in run_wsgi(self=<mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod.hgwebdir object>, req=<mercurial.hgweb.request.wsgirequest object>)
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc in templater(self=<mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod.hgwebdir object>, req=<mercurial.hgweb.request.wsgirequest object>)
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mercurial\templater.pyc in stylemap(styles=(None, None, 'paper'), paths=[])
<type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: No hgweb templates found in [] 
      args = ('No hgweb templates found in []',) 
      message = 'No hgweb templates found in []'.
```

I have copied the Templates folder from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\Templates to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hg\Templates. Some instructions refer to the’templates’ folder, so I tried renaming Templates to templates with no difference.

Is there somewhere else I should be putting the Templates folder, or is there somewhere I should be specifying the templates path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the path to the Templates folder in the hgweb.config file

```
[web]
templates = c:\inetpub\wwwroot\hg\Templates
```